# am i doing it right regarding C# using statement?

Tags: c#

both SmtpClient and MailMessage implements IDisposable so i thought of making my code like this

```
using (SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient("xxx", 587))
{
    smtpClient.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("email", "pass");
    smtpClient.EnableSsl = true;

    using (MailMessage mail = new MailMessage())
    {
        mail.Subject = "subject";
        mail.From = new MailAddress("email", "name");
        mail.To.Add(new MailAddress("email"));
        mail.Body = "body";
        mail.IsBodyHtml = true;

        smtpClient.Send(mail);
    }  
}
```

am i doing it right using 2 using statements or only the first using statement is necessary?

thanks

Comment: if both need to be disposed, then a `using` on both is necessary.

Comment: The comment immediately above is wrong and you should ignore it.

Comment: @Enfyve your whole statement is simply not true and it's better to delete it to not confuse readers.

Comment: @Evk well I'm left scratching my head - I was under the impression that the GC disposed of objects when the declaring function returned or the declaring class was disposed. I can see where the nesting using statement was silly of me to say.

Comment: @Enfyve GC does not dispose objects at all (does not call Dispose method of IDisposable). If class has finalizer - GC will call it when collecting the object, but this might happen any time in the future, so it is not valid to rely on that. So if class implements IDisposable - you should call it when you are done with the instance of that class, you should not rely on that class having finalizer and GC calling that some time in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When nesting `using` statements, it’s more idiomatic to do it without indentation:

```
using (SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient("xxx", 587))
using (MailMessage mail = new MailMessage())
{
    smtpClient.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("email", "pass");
    smtpClient.EnableSsl = true;

    mail.Subject = "subject";
    mail.From = new MailAddress("email", "name");
    mail.To.Add(new MailAddress("email"));
    mail.Body = "body";
    mail.IsBodyHtml = true;

    smtpClient.Send(mail);
}
```

This isn’t always possible, because you sometimes need to do some processing between the first and the second `using`. It works in your example, though.

Comment: does this mean that once the using block ends, all objects in it that were instantiated using 'using' statement (just like the smtpClient) gets disposed too?

Comment: @HeeroYuy Yes, absolutely right. It’s no magic, by the way. It works exactly like nesting `if`s without braces, as in `if (a > b) if (b > c) if (d == e) { /* do stuff */ }`. The same would be if you added braces, yielding `if (a > b) { if (b > c) { if (d == e) { /* do stuff */ }}}`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I understand better now :)

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing inherently wrong with having multiple using statements. It keeps the lifetime of objects to the minimum which is not a bad thing to do.